# Convert parts of strings to another character set

Tags: linux, bash

I need to display the text in the **utf-8** encoding.

```
echo "sometext1 ${DATA[1]} \
sometext2 ${DATA[2]} \
sometext3 ${DATA[3]} \
sometext4 ${DATA[4]} \
sometext5 ${DATA[5]}"
```

- sometext* text with the encoding of **utf-8**
- ${DATA[1]} Contains digits
- ${DATA[2]} Contains digits
- ${DATA[3]} Contains text with the encoding of **windows-1251**
- ${DATA[4]} Contains digits
- ${DATA[5]} Contains text with the encoding of **windows-1251**

I tried to do the following:

```
DATA_A=$(${DATA[3]}|iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8")
DATA_B=$(${DATA[5]}|iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8")

echo "sometext1 ${DATA[1]} \
sometext2 ${DATA[2]} \
sometext3 $DATA_A \
sometext4 ${DATA[4]} \
sometext5 $DATA_B"
```

And I do not get the conversion of a part of line text.

If i just convert these variables, then everything good:

```
echo ${DATA[3]}|iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8"
echo ${DATA[5]}|iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` was missing in following commands

```
DATA_A=$(echo "${DATA[3]}"|iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8")
DATA_B=$(echo "${DATA[5]}"|iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8")
```

or to avoid a pipe

```
DATA_A=$(iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8" <<< "${DATA[3]}")
DATA_B=$(iconv -f "windows-1251" -t "UTF-8" <<< "${DATA[5]}")
```

Comment: Thanks for second solution!